# configuration of django_mongodb_engine with django 1.8 or any other way to use MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I have configure django_mongodb_engine with django 1.6 version but i am not able to configure it with 1.8 version. I have used steps given on this site 
https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

According to my R and D, django mongodb engine doesn't supports django 1.8, As they are using django-nonrel