# What versions of Django does the Django MongoDB Engine support?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

Is the maintenance and support for Django MongoDB Engine still active? I searched online and found that the original author of Django MongoDB Engine already quit the project. I am wondering if it supports Django 1.8. If not, I would switch to another mongo ORM such as mongoengine.
Related question (with no answers): [configuration of django_mongodb_engine with django 1.8 or any other way to use MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044454/configuration-of-django-mongodb-engine-with-django-1-8-or-any-other-way-to-use-m)

Comment: Does not seem like it, according to the changelog here: https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/meta/changelog.html

Comment: @NightShadeQueen It seems to only support up to 1.6. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Django-mongodb-engine is no longer keeping up with the latest Django improvements As a web developer you can take up the challenge of connecting Django to MongoDB in several ways, but depending on what strategy you chose you may run out support from the authors sooner or later. There are several reasons for that. Listed below are some:

**Use a MongoDB compatible model framework**: Use a third party framework like [MongoEngine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) or [Ming](https://github.com/amol-/ming) in your django projects. However will miss out on:

- 1500+ core contributors to the project,
- [Hourly fixes and ticket resolution](https://dashboard.djangoproject.com/),
- Ramp down on the expertise of existing Django models and ramp up on the new model framework.
- Perhaps the biggest drawback is that your project can’t use any of Django’s contrib models! Forget about using Admin, Sessions, Users, Auth, etc., contrib modules for your project!

Alternatively you can try:

**Django SQL to MongoDB connector — [Djongo](http://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)**: The strategy is to translate Django SQL query syntax generated by the Django ORM into pymongo commands. Djongo is a SQL to MongoDB query compiler. It translates every SQL query string into a mongoDB query document.

**SQL syntax will never change** regardless of future additions to Django, by using a connector instead of a different ORM, your project **will work on all versions of Django**.